# Committing changes on server with git-deploy

Tags: git, deployment, git-deploy

I am using [git-deploy](https://github.com/mislav/git-deploy) to upload changes to my server. My website is WordPress though my problem is shared with any application where file are uploaded.

When I upload files through the application they are not added to the repo (which would require `git add` and `git commit`. I want these uploaded files to be in source control. I SSHed into the server and I noticed that the actual web root is not a git repo. That makes sense and is create security. However, it makes adding files to git more difficult.

How do I add the files that are uploaded to my web server to my git repository when I am using **git-deploy** to handle my deployments?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36730120/641955

Comment: That is an interesting idea. I suspect that it might cause a conflict with `git-deploy` but it is certainly worth investigating.